# Android Contact: how to achieve the same picture "expansion" in a popup

Tags: android, imageview, expansion

I guess that you know the ICS contact application.

There is a fancy and usefull way to display pictures in a cropped way and then on a click, the full picture appear.

I just wanted to know how to achieve this..

Is that a new Activity?

Should I create a popup with the full picture and create the animation in the same Activity?

Thank a lot for any help..

[image]

I have already tried:

```
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    ActivityDetail.this);
            ImageView view = new ImageView(ActivityDetail.this);
            //build the view
            builder.setView(view);

            builder.create().show();

        }
    });
```

The big problem is the animation!

The dialog is not as neat as the Contact apps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use scaleType attribute of ImageView like this,

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="200dp"  
               android:layout_height="200dp"  
               android:layout_gravity="center"  
               android:src="@drawable/eureka"  
               android:scaleType="matrix">  
   </ImageView>
```

android:scaleType has different values given on [android:scaleType samples](http://etcodehome.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html)

then,
You can pass the imagesourceid as intent extra somewhat like this.

> ```
> Intent newintent = new Intent(test.this, image.class);
> newintent.putExtra("IMAGE", R.drawable.yor_image);
> ```

and then accept in the destination activity and use as below

```
int imgid = getIntent().getIntExtra("IMAGE", 0);
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
img.setImageResource(imgid);
```

Comment: Yes, I succeed doing that, the big problem is the transition between both activities.. Just try the contact app, you will unedrstand

Comment: tell me the exact problem that you are facing now and I haven't used contact app in ICS I'll try it get u back soon

Comment: As you can see in the picture I posted the first image is cropped with scaleType="center_crop", then when the user click, it expands in a popup in a smooth and nice animation... Not so easy to describe... I currently use fade animation, but an "opening" animation would be nice